# Issue in streaming 360 videos in Unity for VR while using OzoPlayerSdk

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am facing problem in streaming videos on Ozo player sdk.

As per the documentation given I tried keeping http url in .playlist file 
and in AppStateManager kept link for youtube in place for Server Url field.

The player on runtime indicates to download a video instead of streaming it and does nothing from the point.

Also it indicates of creating a .json file for Url provided in server url field.

Error i get is:

Starting download: https://www.youtube.com/videos.jsonUnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)OZO.DownloadCache:DownloadFile(Uri, Boolean) (at Assets/Scripts/Data/DownloadCache.cs:93)OZO.VideoDownloadManager:GetVideosAsync(Uri, Action`1) (at Assets/Scripts/Data/VideoDownloadManager.cs:387)OZO.AppStateManager:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/App/AppStateManager.cs:127)

Failed to download: https://www.youtube.com/videos.jsonUnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)OZO.c__AnonStoreyA:<>m__D(String) (at Assets/Scripts/Data/DownloadCache.cs:189)OZO.Download:ReportComplete(String) (at Assets/Scripts/Data/Download.cs:183)OZO.Download:Cancel() (at Assets/Scripts/Data/Download.cs:243)OZO.Download:handleDownloadResponse(UnityWebRequest, Download) (at Assets/Scripts/Data/Download.cs:330)OZO.c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets/Scripts/Data/Download.cs:315)UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)

Failed loading video entriesUnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)OZO.AppStateManager:onVideoListDownloaded(Dictionary`2) (at Assets/Scripts/App/AppStateManager.cs:134)OZO.c__AnonStoreyC:<>m__10(String) (at Assets/Scripts/Data/VideoDownloadManager.cs:363)OZO.Download:ReportComplete(String) (at Assets/Scripts/Data/Download.cs:183)OZO.Download:Cancel() (at Assets/Scripts/Data/Download.cs:243)OZO.Download:handleDownloadResponse(UnityWebRequest, Download) (at Assets/Scripts/Data/Download.cs:330)OZO.c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets/Scripts/Data/Download.cs:315)UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)

Please help on the same. Step by step procedure for the same would be helpful.

Also need to know what features we get to use in paid version of sdk.

Answer (score 1):

For the record the HTTP stream has to respect the MPEG-DASH format with AVC1 or AVC3 codec (this is what the SDK supports). That means the format of the URL has to end with a .mpd

example: http://vm2.dashif.org/livesim-dev/periods_60/xlink_30/insertad_1/testpic_2s/Manifest.mpd

I don't know what format you used but if it tries to download, you probably don't have the right format.

If you want to deliver youtube videos as DASH, I advise you to read this:  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/guides/encoding-with-dash

**BUT** I have been talking to the dev team of the SDK as I also cannot read my stream (though it does not try to download it) and have been told that there is currently a problem which makes the **whole streaming part unsuable**. They should release a fix ASAP (though they did not give me a date).